# How to detect Ctrl+key in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, keyboard-events

After looking at the Dojo 1.10 documentation for [`dojo/on`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html) and [`dojo/keys`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/keys.html), I still don't understand how to handle an event for a key combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

```js
on(document, "keydown", function (evt) {
    var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    // capture Ctrl+N
    if (evt.ctrlKey && charOrCode === 78 /* This works, but doesn't use the keys module */) {
```

Dojo has constants in `keys` for other keys like `keys.ENTER`, but there are no such keys listed for letters in the documentation. Similarly, there are no examples of key combinations being handled. It doesn't seem right to use a hard-coded `keyCode`, since [that property is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). One of the major purposes of Dojo is cross-browser compatibility.

Do I have to set a flag when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed and handle the key events as two separate events if I want to be cross-browser? I think there should be an easier way...

[This is why the keys modules exists.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (see the large tables of differences between browsers)

Comment: why you mentiend that ctrlKey is being deprecated ?

Comment: @BooBerr'ita [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), not `ctrlKey`.